# repaint() not calling paintComponent() in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent, repaint

I am writing what should be a simple piece of code that creates a JFrame object and then paints the background black and draws a blue square.  However, the repaint() method is not calling the paintComponent() method.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Container;

public class Snake extends JPanel{
        private Vector xCoords = new Vector();
        private Vector yCoords = new Vector();

        public Snake(){
                xCoords.add(150);
                yCoords.add(150);
        }

        public void startJFrame(){
                JFrame window = new JFrame();
                window.setSize(300, 300);
                window.setVisible(true);
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                Container c = window.getContentPane();
                c.setBackground(Color.black);
        }

        public void paintRequest(){
                System.out.println("Request to paint received.");
                repaint();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                System.out.println("paintComponent was called");
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                int x = (int)xCoords.get(0);
                int y = (int)yCoords.get(0);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
                Snake mkFrame = new Snake();
                mkFrame.startJFrame();
                mkFrame.paintRequest();
        }
}
```

I know that paintRequest() is being called properly because it prints "Request to paint received", but "paintComponent was called" is never printed.  On the gui side, the JFrame window is created and it has a black background, but there is no blue square.  Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Tip: When overriding any method, use the `@Override` notation to check the method spelling and signature.

Comment: You might also want to consider using a `Point` object for the x/y values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Snake` ever added to the frame!

Change:

```
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
```

To:

```
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.add(new Snake());
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot this.  Thank you.  However, this makes the background the default greyish white, not black.  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: The panel entirely covers the content pane of the frame. Don't bother setting the color of the frame, just that of the panel.